# How to unit test Angular directive with @input alias

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine, angular-directive

I want to show/hide elements according to a user's role (some buttons shall just be visible for admins for instance). This can be achieved with *ngIf, I believe a better approach is a directive though:

```
import { Directive, Input, TemplateRef, ViewContainerRef } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService } from '../services/auth.service';

@Directive({
    selector: '[appHasRole]',
})
export class HasRoleDirective {
    constructor(private auth: AuthService, private templateRef: TemplateRef<any>, private viewContainer: ViewContainerRef) {}

    @Input() set appHasRole(role: string) {
        if (this.checkRole(role)) {
            this.viewContainer.createEmbeddedView(this.templateRef);
        } else {
            this.viewContainer.clear();
        }
    }

    checkRole(role: string): boolean {
        return this.auth.getRole() === role;
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
<div *appHasRole="'admin'">
```

This works as expected. I struggle to write a unit test for the component though. Despite reading the [testing examples](https://angular.io/guide/testing-attribute-directives) in the official Angular documentation and some related posts ([Angular 2 / 4 - How to test Directive @Input values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45285556/angular-2-4-how-to-test-directive-input-values) and [How to test the set method of @Input in an Angular directives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49686468/how-to-test-the-set-method-of-input-in-an-angular-directives)), I could not make it work.

I'm struggling because I do not use a separated input like

```
<div *appHasRole [role]="'admin'">
```

but use an [@input alias](https://angular.io/guide/attribute-directives#bind-to-an-input-alias).

**Attempt 1:**

```
@Component({
    template: `<div *appHasRole="'admin'" class="test"></div>`,
})
class TestComponent {
    @ViewChild(HasRoleDirective) directive: HasRoleDirective;
}

beforeEach(async(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        declarations: [HasRoleDirective, TestComponent],
        providers: [AuthService, HasRoleDirective, TemplateRef, ViewContainerRef],
    }).createComponent(TestComponent);
    testDirective = new HasRoleDirective(new AuthService(), new TemplateRef(), new ViewContainerRef());
}))
```

I did not even add any unit tests here because ViewContainerRef [is an abstract class and cannot be directly instantiated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62055339/14312803). So I don't see any way of testing

```
this.viewContainer.createEmbeddedView(this.templateRef);
```

with this approach.

**Attempt 2:**

```
@Component({
    template: `<div *appHasRole="'admin'"></div>`,
})
class TestComponent {
    @ViewChild(HasRoleDirective) directive: HasRoleDirective;
}

let directive: DebugElement;
let testComponent: TestComponent;

beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        declarations: [HasRoleDirective, TestComponent],
        imports: [HttpClientModule, RouterTestingModule],
        providers: [HasRoleDirective, TemplateRef, ViewContainerRef],
    }).createComponent(TestComponent);

    fixture.detectChanges();
    testComponent = fixture.componentInstance;
    directive = fixture.debugElement.query(By.directive(HasRoleDirective));
    console.log(directive);
});
```

The directive is always null, which prevents further tests. Even when I try to access it with a helper class:

**Attempt 3:**

```
@Component({
    template: `<div *appHasRole="'admin'" class="test"></div>`,
})
class TestComponent {
    @ViewChild(HasRoleDirective) directive: HasRoleDirective;
}

let directive: DebugElement;
let testComponent: TestComponent;

beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        declarations: [HasRoleDirective, TestComponent],
        imports: [HttpClientModule, RouterTestingModule],
        providers: [HasRoleDirective, TemplateRef, ViewContainerRef],
    }).createComponent(TestComponent);

    fixture.detectChanges();
    testComponent = fixture.componentInstance;
    directive = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('.test'));
    console.log(directive);
});
```

Can anyone give me a hint?

Comment: What are you trying to test? The directive or the component? Also [this](https://angular.io/api/core/testing/tick) may help, dom isn't initialized until after `ngAfterViewInit`

Comment: I'm trying to test the directive. I'm not sure how ngAfterViewInit would help me? Shouldn't [fixture.detectChanges()](https://angular.io/api/core/testing/ComponentFixture#methods) take care of the changes in the DOM? Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you are trying to test **directive's class**, if so let me tell you that you should not test the **directive's class**, instead you should test the **directive's behavior**. Also shown in the official documentation [here](https://angular.io/guide/testing-attribute-directives)(You posted this link already)

Your **Attempt 3:** works fine for me

```
directive = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('.test'));

^^also this is not directive but host debug element, to be precise this is your `div` tag which has the directive
```

I suspect your service is asynchronous so you get `null` above for `directive`, It is always a good idea to mock your service, Below is the complete working example

```js
@Injectable()
export class MockAuthService {
  getRole() {
    return 'admin';
  }
}

@Component({
  template: `<div *appHasRole="userRole" class="test" data-test="myDiv">div tag is visible</div>`,
})
class TestComponent {
  userRole = '';
}

describe('HasRoleDirective', () => {
  beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [
        TestComponent,
        HasRoleDirective
      ],
      providers: [
        {
          provide: AuthService,
          useClass: MockAuthService
        }
      ]
    }).compileComponents();
  });

  it('should display div if admin', () => {
    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TestComponent);
    const component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();

    let myDiv = fixture.debugElement
      .query(By.css('[data-test="myDiv"'));
    //Should not be available in DOM
    expect(myDiv).toBeNull();

    component.userRole = 'admin';
    fixture.detectChanges();

    myDiv = fixture.debugElement
      .query(By.css('[data-test="myDiv"'));
    //Should be available in DOM
    expect(myDiv).not.toBeNull();
  });
});
```

Your **Attempt 2:** won't work because...someone already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57796556/11719787)